# Updating .NET Core on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-server-2012

We just had a pen test completed and one of my servers was hit with an out of date version of .NET core.  Now, in the old days of .NET Framework, I would just install the newest version on the server and call it a day.  However, I'm not sure about .NET Core and what would happen if I slap v6 on there and what it will do to my existing applications.  Will I be ok or do we need to update all of the applications that use that older version of .NET core when we update the version on the server?

Comment: You have to edit the question to make clear what you would like to discuss. If you just want to focus on a single issue from pen test report, reveal the details and others might suggest solutions. If you want a general discussion on how to keep .NET Core runtime on a machine up-to-date, then that can only lead to lengthy discussions and lengthy answers.

Comment: @lex-Li, is there a way to keep .net core up to date?  If so, I would like to pass that on to my Sys Ops team so that they can have those updates as part of the patching cycle.  Otherwise, I'll have to manually update .NET Core on our servers each time there's a new release or a pen test pops us.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/ You can probably go through this article with your operation team to see what's their feedback. Anyway, open a support case with Microsoft via https://support.microsoft.com is the most common way to learn such, not from any online forum like this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should update the old .net core version to newest version.

As far as I know for LTS .net core, MSFT will update it for each version.

Like 3.1, 5.0, 6.0, you could follow this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet) version to download the newest version.

But if your application is built by 2.1 and it is out of date, if you remove the 2.1 runtime, it may caused some issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid of removing that old runtime, because we do have a couple of apps using it, and don't want to do an update on those this close to Christmas.